# How to separate color errorbar matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Given the following example code:

```
x = 0:pi/10:pi;
y = sin(x);
e = std(y)*ones(size(x));

figure
errorbar(x,y,e)
```

How are you able to color the line different compared to the horizontal lines?

I tried

```
errorbar(x,y,e,'--mo')
```

But this changes all of them together...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get a handle to the `errorbar` object. It has two children, corresponding to the data plot and error bars respectively. Then you can set the color of each separately.

```
h = errorbar(x,y,e) %// a color spec here would affect both data and error bars
hc = get(h, 'Children')
set(hc(1),'color','b') %// data
set(hc(2),'color','g') %// error bars
```

Comment: awesome, this is much simpler to the linespec mumbo jumbo

Answer (score 3):

In 2014b the error bar object doesn't have children [anymore](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbarseries-properties.html). One (ugly) way of circumventing this is to plot the function *again* with a different color. Effectively this plots the function with a new color on top of the function with the old color.

```
hold on;
errorbar(x, y, e, 'r'); % // The color here will stay for the error bars
plot(x, y, 'b');        %// Here we change the color of the original function
```

Comment: You can hide the lineplot in errorbar at all: `errorbar(x, y, e, 'r', 'LineStyle', 'none');`