# How to color errorbars individually in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to color errorbars individually in Matlab but can't seem to figure it out. A similar post and answer by Luis Mendo in 2015 recommended the code below, but this method is outdated and does not work because child objects for error bars are 0x0 place holders now.

```
h = errorbar(x,y,e) %// a color spec here would affect both data and error bars
hc = get(h, 'Children')
set(hc(1),'color','b') %// data
set(hc(2),'color','g') %// error bars
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010833/2586922) to an old question (from 2014, not sure if that's the one you are referring to)

Comment: There is an updated answer in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make each error bar a different color, you can essentially recreate the errorbar plot function and scale the color proportionally with the error associated with each specific point:

```
clc; clear all;

x=1:30;
y=rand(length(x),1);
e=rand(length(x),1);

plot(x,y,'k');hold on;

max(e);
range=min(x)-max(x);
inc=range/100;
for i=1:length(x)
    c=[e(i)/max(e) (max(e)-e(i))/max(e) 0];
    plot([x(i) x(i)],[y(i)-e(i) y(i)+e(i)],'Color',c);
    plot([x(i)-inc x(i)+inc],[y(i)-e(i) y(i)-e(i)],'Color',c);
    plot([x(i)-inc x(i)+inc],[y(i)+e(i) y(i)+e(i)],'Color',c);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant thing ever but you could just plot over the errorbar plot with a standard line plot with the desired color:

```
clc; clear all;

x=1:100;
y=rand(length(x),1);
e(1:length(x))=1;

h = errorbar(x,y,e,'r')
hold on;
plot(x,y,'b');
```

[image]